# Error while connecting to computer

Tags: itunes, ipad, mail.app, email, restore

I restarted my ipad becasue cannot access to my email accounts, went off showing a no stop wheel and connect to my computer a message comes "unknown error QxE8000065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to restore your iPad.  Hold down the top and bottom buttons till the screen goes black and you see the Apple symbol.  Then follow the instructions on this page http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1808  to restore your iOS.   I think once you do this and re-sync your ipad a lot of your problems (that you have posted about on here today) will be resolved.

Comment: A lot of these today, ha. +1